# Result is null exception from language-ext when working with monads

Tags: c#, monads, language-ext

Why does this throw a "Result is null" exception? Shouldn't the None propagate through and set "a" equal to None?

```
public void test()
{
    Option<string> a = match(
        from b in ReturnNull()
        select b,
        x => x,
        () => null
    );
}

private Option<string> ReturnNull()
{
    return None;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `null` is not valid value for `Option<string>`. The whole point of `Option` is to avoid nulls and related null reference exceptions, but what you are doing is assigning null as a result when `b` is None:

```
Option<string> a = match(
    from b in ReturnNull()
    select b,
    x => x,
    // here
    () => null
);
```

`Option<string>` where value is null is not valid, because for nulls you should use `None`, so it throws an exception.

Match is used to unwrap `Option` value, so there is no reason actually to assign result of match to another `Option`. Instead, assign to underlying type variable (`string` in this case):

```
string a = match(
    from b in ReturnNull()
    select b,
    x => x,
    () => null
);
```

Or just use `var`, because `match` return type is `string` in this case.

Of course this piece of code makes little sense, because you essentially just throw away `Option` and return back to regular nullable string, but I assume this is just an example and not real code.